# Big problems with shared SugarCRM database

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, sugarcrm

Here is my situation: 
I have two hosting sites with a domain each, each with Sugarcrm infrastructure. I started with one hosting site and started creating a database through Sugar. Then, I started a SECOND hosting site with a new domain, and I believe I have linked the two databases accidentally. If I change a value in the database on one site, it gets reflected on the other.

So, the original domain/hosting site is expiring, and I would like to move the SQL database over to the new site permanently. I have made a backup of the database from the original site and have it on my desktop.

My questions:
1. Can I just drag the SQL file into the new site (I use FileZilla) database location and everything will be OK?
2. I cannot find the location in file manager of the new site where I would drag this database into!? I use goddady, and the newer site uses cpanel.

**Other problem: I have accidentally upgraded the newer sites SugarCrm version, and have created huge problems because the original site is not upgraded, and the sites do not like that very much as the database is shared. There original site is unreachable (it says you cannot use the newer version database with the old Sugar version), and the new site has visible problems but is workable.

As you can tell, I am a totally inexperienced n00b, and am learning as I go. I have spent weeks setting up this database, and would appreciate any help on maintaining its integrity.

Thank you very much!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using MySQL for your database.

Unless your tables are all MyISAM tables, simply copying the database files won't work.

Whenever you want to move a MySQL database it's a good idea to dump the database, move that file over, then recreate the database.  Read up on the mysqldump command.

If you're using Oracle or something else, I would think a similar technique would be desirable.  Basically dump your database to a backup format that your database server can use to recreate your database.  Don't just copy database files around.